# Using reinterpret_cast to parse templated network data

Tags: c++, c++17, reinterpret-cast

I am looking into a protocol that sends little endian data over a network and my machine is also little endian. I will not be concerned with big endian machines.

Separate from the data sent over the network, is a template file that instructs how to interpret the data.

For the sake of this question let's just say that the only template instructs to parse data as a 4 byte integer immediately followed by a 8 byte integer.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class Int32 final {
public:
    Int32(
        const char* const a_buf,
        const int         a_offset
    ) :
        m_buf   (a_buf),
        m_offset(a_offset)
    {}

    int32_t getVal() const { return *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(m_buf + m_offset); }

private:
    const char* const m_buf;
    const int         m_offset;
};

class Int64 final {
public:
    Int64(
        const char* const a_buf,
        const int         a_offset
    ) :
        m_buf   (a_buf),
        m_offset(a_offset)
    {}

    int64_t getVal() const { return *reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(m_buf + m_offset); }

private:
    const char* const m_buf;
    const int         m_offset;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Make up some data for the sake of a SO example
    //
    // The real data is sent over a network with little endian ordering and my
    // machine is also little endian
    char buf[12];
    *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(buf + 0) = 42;
    *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(buf + 4) = 69;

    // Example of "applying a template" to the data, in this case the "template"
    // is just a 4 byte int followed by a 8 byte int
    const Int32 foo(buf, 0);
    const Int64 bar(buf, 4);

    std::cout << foo.getVal() << " " << bar.getVal() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I am populating `buf` myself, in the real code `buf` is populated by copying the data sent over the network.

What I am concerned about is if there is any undefined behavior related to the two `getVal` methods.

Is it safe to `reinterpret_cast` `m_buf + m_offset`?

Comment: then you are in UB land.  The way to do it in C++17 and be legal is to create an object of the type you want and then `memcpy` the buffer into that object.

Comment: You should have `(buf + 0) % alignof(std::uint32_t) == 0` and `(buf + 4) % alignof(std::uint64_t) == 0`, else your data would be unaligned.

Comment: What you are doing is called (binary) Serialization and it is a non-trivial problem (endianness, different sizes of int on differetent systems. 8/16/32/64 bits). With classes you will probably fail to ensure objects are properly constructed (see std::bit_cast, it is easy to reimplement in C++17).  My advise just use a library for that like flatbuffers or protobuf. (there are more).

Comment: @NathanOliver For C++17 it is indeed memcpy, but use [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (C++20), or  [std::start_lifetime_as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as) (C++23)

Comment: @NathanOliver, If I understand correctly you are saying that I need actual `int32_t` and `int64_t` members to `memcpy` into? If yes, then why is it that `memcpy` avoids the UB that `reinterpret_cast` would be causing?

Comment: @asimes its about object lifetimes.  `char buf[12];` is a char array, not a `int32_t`, or `int64_t`, which means when you do `*reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(m_buf + m_offset)`, you are aceesing an object that does not exist.  When you create an object and then `memcpy` into you are working with an actual object that exists.